# Xamarin - Cannot add reference to another PCL Project

Tags: xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I have created a Xamarin.Forms solution and I want to add another layer to access the API. So I added another PCL Project to the same solution and tried to add a reference to this new project from the PCL Project that comes by default in Xamarin.Forms. But it does not allow me to add a reference and gives me this error. Can you tell me why this is happening, how to get over it or how to add a PCL reference correctly?

[image: Error when trying to add a reference]

Comment: There are few templates for PCL, make sure you select one with description: for Android, iOS and Windows

Comment: @YuriS Yeah but that will add the whole list of other projects as well. i.e. Android, iOS and UWP projects. Other than that, we cannot add a reference just to a  Class Library? I selected the project which says 'Class Library (Xamarin.Forms)'

Comment: how you created other projects? using forms? shared or PCL? I don't see either of them in your solution

Comment: you are not adding PCL reference to another PCL, are you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to [read up](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/) on what a PCL exactly is.

In short: a PCL has a [specific profile](https://portablelibraryprofiles.stephencleary.com/), which is specified by the platforms you are targeting. If you go into the properties of your PCL project, you can check each platform that you want to target. With each extra target that you check, the profile changes. The profile defines what subset of the .NET framework is available to you.

For instance, the other day there was a question about the `String.Copy` method. If this method is supported by .NET framework 4.5, but not Xamarin.iOS and you target these two, the method is not available to you. Only the parts of the .NET framework are available that are in the intersection of all platforms that you target. So each target that you target should support the methods that you can use.

That being said; this is also the reason why referencing another PCL should have the same platforms targeted.